# How to access the properties on a XML Node via linq?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323738/how-do-i-get-all-properties-from-xml-via-linq-to-xml) post.

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Export version="" srcSys="" dstSys="" srcDatabase="" timeStamp="">

    </Export>
```

This is what i tried, but with no luck:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(BuyingModule.Properties.Resources.Export);

Func<XElement, string, string> GetAttribute = (e, property) => e.Elements("property").Where(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == property).Single().Value;

var query = from record in xml.Elements("Export")
            select record;

var prop = GetAttribute(query.FirstOrDefault(), "version");
```

How do i access to `properties` of the "Export" Node?

I need to set those `properties`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Export` element doesn't *have* a `properties` element, which is what your `GetAttribute` method is trying to find.

My guess is you *actually* want:

```
var element = xml.Element("Export"); // Just get the first element
var version = (string) element.Attribute("version");
```

It's not clear to me why you've used a query expression and a delegate here - it's just things more complicated than you need. But [`Attribute(XName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute.aspx) is probably what you were missing...

Comment: Thanks for the help Jon. Looked like i didn't need the first line tho(`var element = xml.Element("Export");)`. I went straight: `var version = xml.Attribute("version");`

Comment: @Willem: Ah - I assumed that because you were looking for `Export` elements in your query, that the XML you'd actually parsed had a top level element above it...